# bash - copying multiple files with the same name

Tags: bash

I would like to copy files that are under the same name but in different folders into destdir. The issue is about not overwriting them in destdir.

Basically this could be enough, although I have no clue how to rename each of the file. As for now they all being overwritten:

> $ cp /src/folder/*/file ~/dest/*

Comment: Note: your `cp` command is very wrong. I guess you wanted the second asterisk to "pull" its value from the first, but this never happens. If `~/dest/` wasn't empty, you could end up copying things you don't want into a directory you don't expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one method:

```
cd /src/folder
for f in */file; do
    cp -v "$f" ~/dest/"${f//\//_}"
done
```

that will copy `/src/folder/foobar/file` to `~/dest/foobar_file` which should be unique

Answer (score 3):

You can see whether the `--backup` option of `cp` is available (I believe it isn't on MacOS, but I might be wrong):

```
 cp --backup=t /src/folder/*/file /dest
```

will create file.jpg.~1~, file.jpg.~2~ and so on.