# bash-copying multiple files with the same name

Tags: linux, bash

I have the same question, which was asked before -

[bash - copying multiple files with the same name](https://superuser.com/questions/1333555/bash-copying-multiple-files-with-the-same-name)

I would like to copy files that are under the same name but in different folders into new dir. The issue is about not overwriting them in new dir.

E.g.,
I want to copy **final_fasta.fna** from multiple folders to another folder:

```
    12345A-99-85/assembly/final_fasta.fna

    12345A-99-52/assembly/final_fasta.fna

    12345A-99-81/assembly/final_fasta.fna
```

If I do this-

```
    cp 12345A-99-*/assembly/final_fasta.fna ~/output_direc/
```

then it will overwrite the "**final_fasta.fna**" in the **~/output_direc/** folder

I want something like in the output folde

```
   ~/output_direc/12345A-99-85_final_fasta.fna
```

Comment: The directory from where I am trying to copy things, I don't have permission to write, therefore, I can not create directory.

Comment: What about the solutions listed in the other question? Why don't they work for you (i.e. rewriting the filename in a loop)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mkdir -p {12345A-99-85,12345A-99-52,12345A-99-81}/assembly
$ touch {12345A-99-85,12345A-99-52,12345A-99-81}/assembly/final_fasta.fna
$ mkdir ~/output_direc
$ find . -name "final_fasta.fna" -type f -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" ~/output_direc/"$(dirname "$1" | cut -d / -f2)"_final_fasta.fna' sh {} \; 
$ ls -Al ~/output_direc/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 16 12:12 12345A-99-52_final_fasta.fna
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 16 12:12 12345A-99-81_final_fasta.fna
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 0 Sep 16 12:12 12345A-99-85_final_fasta.fna
```

Comment: The directory from where I am trying to copy things, I don't have permission to write, therefore, I can not create directory.  @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: @user309866: there is no need to write anything in a directory you're copying these files from. You *have to* be able to write to `~/output_direc` though.

Comment: @user309866 It may not be obvious but everything before `find` is only to create your example directory structure. This is for users who want to test the solution. The actual solution, when the directory structure is there, is `find …`.